# Запрос с исключением SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

есть две таблицы:

**company** - id, name

**voting** - company_id

Нужно получить только те строки, которых нет в **voting**

Допустим, структура **company**:

id   name

1    name1

2 name2

3 name3

Структура **voting**:

company_id

2

Нужно получить

1    name1

3 name3

Пробовал вот так: `SELECT * FROM company c JOIN voting v ON v.company_id != c.id`
, но результат не тот...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM company c 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM voting v 
                   WHERE v.company_id = c.id )
```

или

```
SELECT * 
FROM company c 
LEFT JOIN voting v ON v.company_id = c.id
WHERE v.company_id IS NULL
```